# Is there a restriction in the use of the idiom "I am done with"?

Tags: idioms, idiomatic-language

Is there a restriction in the use of the idiom "I am done with"? For example, when we say "I am done with the paper", can it mean you finished reading it, writing it, copying it or burning it, etc.? Is there some form of limitation that prevents you to use it any way you want?

The dictionary states:

> finished with someone or something.

But the meaning is so vague, I am not sure if there are limitations that comes with it.

Comment: I'm done with answering uninteresting questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to describe the "limits" of how some idiom can be used, because its use may be quite broad, with any number of variations and nuances.  In general, to be "done with" something implies *completion*, but the details depend on context.  For example, in FumbleFingers comment:

> I'm done with John

implies the speaker does not want any more contact with John, but what this means depends on what we already know about their relationship.  It could be that they are romantic partners, or they are coworkers, or even they are family members who have been fighting.  For example

> I'm done with my brother.  I can't even talk to him about anything remotely political without him foaming at the mouth over everything he thinks is wrong with this country.

Note this may not imply that I never want to see my brother again, but rather that I'm *exasperated* with his behavior, and would prefer never to talk to him about a subject that leads to another tiresome tirade.

In a different context:

> I'm done with *my* paper

naturally implies you've finished *writing* it, while

> I'm done with *her* paper

means you have finished *reading* it, or possibly *editing* it.  Along the same lines:

> I'm done with exams

means you've *completed* your exams for the current school period.  Meanwhile, Lambie's comment:

> I'm done answering uninteresting questions

implies a certain degree of *frustration* with the quality of recently asked questions.

As I said, quite broad.